# In this sentence, is it her or herself?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I realize that this second sentence is a fragment. (It is in a piece of fiction.) Still, I would appreciate it if someone can verify for me that I am using "herself" correctly here. Thank you, kindly!

She saw Jake’s surface, not the multilayered person she had known for years. Not her twin, but someone wholly unrelated to herself.

Comment: **She saw Jake’s surface, not the multilayered person she had known for years.** This is quite unusual English - a person does not have a surface, but perhaps an "outward appearance". I agree that "herself" is not correct in your sentence, and "her" is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I would use 'her'.  'Herself' is strictly reflexive, and should only be used if the subject, in this case 'someone', were referring to her.  You are unrelated to me, not unrelated to myself.

Comment: Or, even more direct:  "Not her twin, but someone wholly unrelated."